# ¿Cómo hacer incremento mientras presiono boton en python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un código de una GUI en Tkinter, y quiero que al presionar el botón, el valor de la salida siga subiendo hasta dejar de presionarlo, y llegar a un límite máximo, hasta ahorita solo incrementa una unidad y tengo que volver a presionar para volver a incrementar. mi código esta así:

```py
def SpUp(p1):
   print('QDU-V-1_support.SpUp')
   global a
   if a < 90:
      a += 1
```

Comment: Necesitas que sí se mantiene presionado suba cada n milisegúndos.?

Comment: Asi es, necesito que si se presiona una sola vez, suba solo una unidad y si lo mantengo presionado suba cada n milisegundos.

Comment: Si bien no tengo experiencia con tkinter podria decirte que puedes tener dos acciones 1 click press y 2 click release,  al hacer click inicias un hilo que comience a incrementar el contador, al soltar el click detener el hilo.

Comment: Si, esa es la duda que tengo en el evento del release tengo una función pero no se como empezar el contador en la primera y terminarlo en la segunda función.

Comment: Podrías poner todo tu codigo o un minimo con el que pueda ejecutar y hacer una pruebas para ayudarte.?

Comment: Si editas la pregunta adicionando un poco más de codigo, podremos entender mejor el contexto en el que te encuentras y ayudarte más facilmente

Answer (score 0):

Debes combinar dos eventos sobre el botón para conseguirlo, estos son `<Button-1>` y `<ButtonRelease-1>`.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
import time


release = True
limit = 100


def click_callback():
    global release
    release = False
    while not release and int(text.get()) < limit:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        text.set(str(int(text.get())+1))

def release_callback(e):
    global release
    release = True



root = Tk()

root.geometry('320x240')
root.resizable(False, False)

text = StringVar()
button = Button(root, textvariable=text)
button.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
text.set('0')

button.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: Thread(target=click_callback, daemon=True).start())
button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', release_callback)

root.mainloop()
```

En el ejemplo, al hacer click en el botón se ejecuta la función `click_callback` en un *Thread* separado para no bloquear la *GUI*. Dentro de esta función se modifica la variable global `release` justo antes de entrar a un bucle en el que se incrementa el valor de la variable `text` cada 0.1 segundos (`time.sleep(0.1)`, importante para que si se suelta el botón al instante solo incremente una unidad), y solo se saldrá del bucle al soltar el botón del *mouse*, momento en el cual se ejecuta la función `release_callback`, que lo único que hace es reestablecer `release = True`, o cualdo se alcanza el límite `limit = 100` (finaliza el bucle que incrementa `text`).

Es importante que hagas uso de *Threads* si quieres utilizar bucles "de larga duración", de lo contrario se congelaría tu *GUI* al ejecutarse la función `click_callback` del ejemplo.

Te dejo un enlace a un sitio web en el que puedes consultar los eventos soportados en *Tkinter*: [Eventos-Tkinter](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)